# javascript xml nodes equality comparison fails in function inside XSLT

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt-1.0

I have an XSLT transformation from XML to TXT file that is giving me problems.

The source file looks like this:

```
<ExportAssegnazioniOperatori DataDal="15/04/2013" DataAl="15/04/2013" DataExport="19/06/2013" OraExport="10:19" ErroriInExport="false">
<AreaAziendale CodiceIE="14" CodiceIEAzienda="" Descrizione="Redazione TG5">
    <Data Giorno="15042013" Festivo="false" Prefestivo="false" Postfestivo="false" NumeroGiorno="735338">
        <Operatore CodiceIEOLD="09000365" CodiceIE="09000365" Matricola="09000365" Badge="" Cognome="RICCETTI" Nome="LAURA" CodiceIEReparto="" CodiceIERapportoLavorativo="" StatoOperatore="L">
            <Turno CodiceIEOLD="XTRA" CodiceIE="XTRA" Descrizione="FUORI SEDE" DescrizioneSintetica="FUORI SEDE" DescrizioneTipologiaTurno="&lt;Nessuna tipologia turno&gt;" Riposo="false" Reperibilita="false" OraInizioTurno="0000" OraFineTurno="0000" NumeroOreTurno="0000" OraInizio="0000" OraFine="0000" NumeroOre="0000" NumeroOreStraordinario="0000" NumeroOreEccedenza="0000" TipoElaborazione="0" TurnoSpeciale="false" TurnoNotturno="false" StatoAssegnazione="1" CodiceIEReparto="" SestoGiornoLavorativo="false" ModalitaOperazione="2" TipoGiornata="1" NotaOperatore="" Pubblicato="false"/>
            <Turno CodiceIEOLD="BORSA" CodiceIE="BORSA" Descrizione="BORSA" DescrizioneSintetica="BORSA" DescrizioneTipologiaTurno="TURNO A" Riposo="false" Reperibilita="false" OraInizioTurno="0600" OraFineTurno="1315" NumeroOreTurno="0715" OraInizio="0600" OraFine="1315" NumeroOre="0715" NumeroOreStraordinario="0000" NumeroOreEccedenza="0000" TipoElaborazione="0" TurnoSpeciale="false" TurnoNotturno="false" StatoAssegnazione="1" CodiceIEReparto="" SestoGiornoLavorativo="false" ModalitaOperazione="2" TipoGiornata="1" NotaOperatore="" Pubblicato="false"/>
        </Operatore>
    </Data>
</AreaAziendale>
</ExportAssegnazioniOperatori>
```

The logic is that for each `Operatore` (ie worker) node I have to generate a single row using the only `Turno` (ie work shift) node that satisfies a certain business condition (namely, to be the first shift in the day). In this example, only the `BORSA` row should pass the test.

The problem is that nothing is in the output: no node passes the `DaStampare(this)` test, which checks the condition (see xsl source below).

If, instead, I copy and paste all the script region *verbatim* in an html page to run the simple javascript, loading that xml from disk, I get the correct result: the first node doesn't pass the test but the second does!

By logging I isolated the problem to a function which tests the equality between two variables, one being the current node, the other being the "good" node in among the siblings.

**Why is it that this test gives me false when ran inside the XSLT transformation, but true if ran inside a web page?**

**EDIT** Let me be clear: this is *not* a problem of being able to run javascript inside this XSLT. If I tweak the function I see the corresponding changes in the result. The `DaStampare` function gets called, I am positive about that. It does not behave like I expect it to **END EDIT**

Don't know if it's relevant, but the XSLT transformation is called from classic ASP.

The XSLT is this (i think this is the 1.1 version). The `DaStampare` function is stripped down to make it more readable, it's not the complete logic:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">
<xsl:script>
    <![CDATA[
function DaStampare(objTurno)
{
    var primoDiurno = null;
    for (i = 0; i < objTurno.parentNode.childNodes.length; i++)
    {
        var objSibling = objTurno.parentNode.childNodes(i);
        // Fake test: here i actually check a bunch of business conditions to find the good node
        if(objSibling.getAttribute("CodiceIE") == "BORSA")
        {
                primoDiurno = objSibling;
        }
    }

    if(primoDiurno != null)
    {
        if(objTurno == primoDiurno) // <--**** THIS IS THE TEST THAT FAILS: IT RETURNS FALSE INSIDE THE XSLT, TRUE INSIDE THE HMTL PAGE
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
]]>
</xsl:script>

<xsl:template match="param-descrizione">RPA</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./ExportAssegnazioniOperatori/AreaAziendale/Data/Operatore" order-by="+../../@Descrizione;+@CodiceIE;+../@NumeroGiorno"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Operatore">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Operatore[Turno]">
    <xsl:if test="@CodiceIE[. != '']">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Turno" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Turno">
    <xsl:if expr="DaStampare(this)">
            <xsl:eval>this.getAttribute("CodiceIE")</xsl:eval> + ...
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This is how i initialize the html page

```
var doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
doc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
doc.async = false;
doc.load("nott.xml");

var nodes = doc.selectNodes("//Turno");
 var a1 =  DaStampare(nodes[0]); // THIS IS FALSE
var a2 = DaStampare(nodes[1]); // THIS IS TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

This test gives false when ran inside the XSLT transformation, but true if ran inside a web page, because the failing test is done with embedded javascript.
The task of XSLT is to process the transformation and create text/data/code containing that javascript code. It's not the task of XSLT to run the javascript code.
If run in an web page, the browser will not only process the XSLT but also run the javascript.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: xslt can and does run javascript, there are dozens of instances of this in my application, even inside <xsl:if> tests. What do you mean?

Comment: @Piddu: Plain XSLT can't run Javascript. It's not mentioned in the specifications of version 1.0 or 2.0. Usual XSLT engines like e.g. libexslt (see http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/EXSLT, used in PHP, a lot of browsers etc.) can't run javascript but are capable to create javascript source code because they can create almost any text. Your environment seems to fail adding javascript support in this case. If it usually works even inside xsl:if, there must be a missing preprocessing step.

Comment: @Piddu: Your Question is about "I have an XSLT transformation from XML to TXT file that is giving me problems". I think that this transformation can't be the problem as it doesn't runs javascript. I can not figure out how XSLT is merged together with other techniques in your environment, but again, that was not your question. What I can do is to give you the hint to look for the failing javascript support. The point is to look at the right place.